# How to properly create a Plug module?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I can create my own Plug Module this way http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/understanding-plug#section-module-plugs

Say, I wanted to check if there's a header in a request and its value and if they were corrent, continue further, if not,  terminate the current request and return a certain status and message, probably in json.

However, returning html or json or anything else from a Plug Module isn't allowed, it can only modify a connection structure passed to it on its way to a controller.

Then how would I do that? Should I add a certain key in it instead and then check for it in a controller? But it'd create a lot of repetition, wouldn't it?

```
   # plug module
   def call(conn, default) do
     if condition1
       assign(conn, :my_key, %{status: :ok, msg: "okkkeey"})
     else
       assign(conn, :my_key, %{status: :error, msg: "we have problems")
   end

   # my_controller
   def action1(conn)
     # check for :my_key and its status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return HTML or JSON from a plug as long as you [halt/1](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#halt/1) at the end.

```
   # plug module
   def call(conn, default) do
     if condition1
       assign(conn, :my_key, %{status: :ok, msg: "okkkeey"})
     else
       conn
       |> send_resp(400, "Something wrong")
       |> halt()
   end
```

If you want to return JSON, you can use [Phoenix.Controller.json/2](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#json/2), however you will need to use the full function name as the function is not imported by default.

```
   def call(conn, default) do
     if condition1
       assign(conn, :my_key, %{status: :ok, msg: "okkkeey"})
     else
       conn
       |> put_status(400)
       |> Phoenix.Controller.json(%{error: "We have problems"})
       |> halt()
   end
```

Comment: If I return html, how can I do all that properly? redirect and then halt? Or wise versa? Or just put status?

Comment: Halt will stop your pipeline, just be sure to call it as the last part of your plug and you can do what you like before it. What you should do in your case depends on the application. For example if the user is not authenticated, you may wish to redirect to the login page with a flash message using `Phoenix.Controller.put_flash`

Comment: also, `Phoenix.Controller.send_resp/3` is undefined or private -- why is that?

Comment: `Phoenix.Controller.send_resp/3` doesn't exist, it is `Plug.Conn.send_resp/3`